# How to specify an analyzer and achieve mapping in ElasticSearch?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, mapping, analyzer

I want to define an analyzer and of course applicate it in my DB elasticsearch

My analyzer seems working, when I test it on a random word it works correctly !

But it isn't the case with mapping step !

Mapping query looks like :

```html
{
  "properties": {
    "es_lib_entite": { 
      "type":           "string",
      "analyzer":       "standard",
      "fields": {
        "tosynonym": { 
          "type":       "string",
          "analyzer":   "folding"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

as u can see Analyzer's name is "folding"

and the content of mapping seems correct ! it returns

```html
"es_lib_entite":{
    "type":"string",
    "search_analyzer":"standard",
    "fields":{
       "folded":{
        "type":"string",
        "analyzer":"folding"
        }
    }
},
```

but when I check the content of es_lib_entite with _search it returns null ! I don't why knowing that I'm pretty new to elasticsearch

Comment: What query are you using?

Comment: Hi @AndreiStefan thank you for your time ! I want to know which query you are talking about ? to define my Analyzer ? or to check if it works ?

Comment: To check if it works

Comment: I simply open the link localhost:9200/first_index/objet_entr/_search then I check the content of  es_lib_entite it returns "es_lib_entite":null ! I'm also using query_string query to look for a random word but that's not seem working @AndreiStefan